# Interactive faceted plot across time?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, interactive, facet

Im trying to build an interactive plot where by i can select from 10 different nationalities by country of birth,  showing the time series of migration numbers across 7 years immigrating into Australia.

I want the different facets to be national figures / trends compared with the various state / region wise figures .

I have the data just needed to know whether there is any other visual story telling capability in R that matches my requirement ( read shiny , dashboard etc)  in terms of the task im trying to accomplish?

whats the best way to go about it?

data

```
structure(list(Year = 2004:2007, Australia = c(-18670L, -14730L, 
-12780L, -15210L), New.Zealand = c(16870L, 18090L, 22100L, 27730L
), UK..CIs...IOM.e. = c(22470L, 27690L, 31720L, 33410L), Sudan = c(5690L, 
3780L, 2440L, 950L), China = c(19090L, 19970L, 27880L, 36340L
), Korea..South = c(5490L, 8110L, 9440L, 9770L), India = c(16340L, 
21820L, 37080L, 49780L), USA = c(3320L, 2700L, 4400L, 2080L), 
    Liberia = c(860L, 570L, 560L, 250L), South.Africa = c(5500L, 
    7530L, 8450L, 11080L), Zimbabwe = c(2150L, 2350L, 2530L, 
    3240L), Region = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Australia", 
    "Queensland", "South Australia ", "Tasmania", "Victoria ", 
    "Western Australia "), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Cant wait to hear some thoughts :)

Comment: please have a look at [how to create a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you want an answer."I have the data" is really not very helpful for us to help you. I'll flag your question as too broad for now.

Comment: I have edited my OP. kindly have a look now Tjebo